# How to set x frame default options in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails 4 this could be done under the config file if it already wasn't default.

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = { 'X-Frame-Options' => 'SAMEORIGIN' }
```

Is there a way to set the headers like that in rails 3.2.22.4? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See these discussions:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6311
- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/7302

`default_headers` configuration option (and 'SAMEORIGIN' on by default) was introduced in version 4.0. Before that headers can be manipulated with custom middlewares, or individually for each action as:

```
headers['X-Frame-Options'] = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```